# Не отрабатывает bash скрипт из cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Есть вот такой простенький скрипт, меняющий тему в соответсвии с промежутком времени:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOUR=$(date +%H)
if [ "$HOUR" -ge "19" ] || [ "$HOUR" -lt "7" ] 
    then
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix-Dark"
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Numix-Dark"
    else
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"
        gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Numix"
fi
```

В cron'е вызываю его раз в 10 минут:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * * bash /home/hackerman/toogle-mode.sh
```

cron запущен и работает (проверял через `systemctl` и эксперементально), но скрипт не отрабатывает почему-то (в выводе `cat /var/log/syslog | grep "cron"` никаких ошибок). Однако при запуске из терминала ручками, скрипт отрабатывает.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: если уже создаете скрипт "типа от хакера", то хоть крон запускайте от имени нужного пользователя. Скорее всего Ваш скрипт запускается от имени рута и ничего не знает о бедном юзере

Comment: давайте вы шутить про имя пользователя будете на тематических сайтах. Запись в кронтабе юзера, а не рута. И кстати, если бы была запись в кронтабе рута, то с чего бы это вдруг скрипт не запускался бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была на поверхности. cron'у доступен лишь ограниченный набор переменных окружения, а для выполнения моего скрипта необходимо было обращение к gsetting, соответственно нужна была переменная `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

В скрипт были добавлены следующие строки:

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
```

Спасибо [этому товарищу](https://askubuntu.com/a/368370/1092425)

Comment: dbus-launch еще помогает

Comment: @eri спасибо, возьму на заметку